# logged In user redirects to login page when entering URL manually (React.js)

Tags: reactjs, redirect, react-router, page-refresh, pageload

I restrict access to certain routes using below function

```
function RequireAuth({ children, redirectTo }) {
 const { user, setUser } = useContext(UserContext);
 return user?.LoggedInStatus === "LoggedIn" ? children : <Navigate to={redirectTo} />;
}
```

**it works with react router Link,**

```
<Link to="/protected">protected</Link>
```

but when I enter URL manually in address bar and hit the enter
it redirects Logged In user to login page

I manage user state using useContext hook

```
export const UserContext = createContext(null);
```

In actual project I fetch user Logged In status from API

But I provided a sample for test purpose and set user state like below:

```
function App() {
 const [user, setUser] = useState({ LoggedInStatus: "LoggedOut" });
 useEffect(() => {
   setTimeout(() => {      
   setUser({ LoggedInStatus: "LoggedIn" })
 }, 1000);
 }, [])
```

I use react-route-dom v6 and Routes are like below

```
<UserContext.Provider value={{ user, setUser }}>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
      <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
      <Route path="/public" element={<PublicPage />} />
      <Route
        path="/protected"
        element={
          <RequireAuth redirectTo="/login">
            <ProtectedPage />
          </RequireAuth>
        }
      />
    </Routes>
  </UserContext.Provider>
```

Also I test it with react-router-dom v5 and the problem is the same

To some extent I can understand that this is because react renders pages client side,
and couldn't recognize user state when page reloads manually.

Could we say it's react.js nature and it's not a problem?
(Considering We can't prevent user enter URL manually, it seems a problem to me)

**How to solve this problem?**

Comment: Is the `UserContext` an accurate representation of your *actual* user auth state? Is it *really* only local component state in `App`? How is `Login` updating the `user` context value? What is the "usual flow" when user **doesn't** direct enter a URL? The default/initial `user` state value is `LoggedInStatus: "LoggedOut"`, so the redirect is happening from the initial render cycle because of this state value.

Comment: @Drew Reese, no the actual project is different, but I provided this simple sample to simulate the problem, in actual project when user login, API returns user status json {username:"jone doe",roles:[],LoggedInStatus:"LoggedIn"} and saves the user token in readonly cookie, and I update context value using setUser, in usual flow user click on link (react router Link) and it is ok, in sample project you can see I update LoggedInStatus with "LoggedIn" in useEffect hook of App.js. you can see sample in this link [Link](https://github.com/dev-bahar/ProtectedRouteSample)

Comment: I see, so the the `user` state is controlled by an API endpoint and asynchronously updated. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Did you ever have any resolution to this? I'm running into the same problem when converting my app the Auth0 with the Auth0Provider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that it seems your initial `user` state matches that of a confirmed unauthenticated user, so the auth wrapper incorrectly redirects users to login *before* the app knows wether or not they are authenticated in the backend.

Start from an intermediate undefined state that is neither `"LoggedIn"` nor `"LoggedOut"`, and conditionally wait for the state/context to update.

```
const [user, setUser] = useState({});
```

...

```
function RequireAuth({ children, redirectTo }) {
  const { user, setUser } = useContext(UserContext);

  if (user.LoggedInStatus === undefined) {
    return null; // or loading indicator, etc...
  }

  return user.LoggedInStatus === "LoggedIn"
    ? children
    : <Navigate to={redirectTo} replace />;
}
```

[image: Edit logged-in-user-redirects-to-login-page-when-entering-url-manually-react-js]